# Why can't I call my named session cookie in my PHP code?

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies

I've been unable to call upon my `$_SESSION` variables ever since I added a specific session name to my script.

**www.ueteribus.com** <--- The login script is hosted here.
**carnal.ueteribus.com** <--- The Cookie is read and displayed here.

```
session_name('LoginSession');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.ueteribus.com');
session_start();
```

I've been unable to get the information to be sent to the subdomain even using that above script.

The below script is used in my login area, it is supposed to display information on the sub domain about login information.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Username'])) 
{
    echo $_SESSION['Username'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this script running on a subdomain of ueteribus.com? Else it won't work.

Comment: No it isn't, but what would I do if it was running on a sub domain? That is what I am trying to figure out, I was trying to use this to test to see if I was doing something wrong on my sub domain. Like what would I change? To load that specific variable? Or is it fine as it is?

Answer (score 1):

Since you answered this script is **not** running on any subdomain of ueteribus.com it won't work.

You specified a specific domain where this cookie will work on, check the PHP documentation. Since this is not the domain the script is running on, the cookie is **not** associated with the script in the right way.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Either adjust the domain to display the right domain or remove the line `session_set_cookie_params` line completely.

Comment: Yes, I already specified that, and I know that. But, I was asking if there was anything wrong with the script that would make it not work on the subdomain?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the script, this is intended behaviour. Please first **read** the PHP docs.. It will only work on subdomains of ueteribus.com and nothing else.

Comment: Yes, I have this exact same script added on the sub domain, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I can't help you like this, did you adjust the domain to reflect the domain the script is running on. Does removing the `session_set_cookie_params` line solve the problem?

Comment: The login script is running on the WWW domain, and the debug area of the script, that was the second bit of that code is running on the Carnal sub domain. It is set to detect if the variable is set, and apparently it isn't detecting it?